# AOSP: where can I find the layout of the new clock (fonts and size)?

Tags: android, layout, clock, lockscreen

As the new clock layout in Android 4.2 is awesome, I would like to use it as a basis for my apps.

Thanks to the beauty of Open Source, the source code is available, but I have been browsing it for hours and never found it.

I know posting no code on StackOverflow is not cool, but I strongly believe that sharing this info might be usefull for other developers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's it but have a look at

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/keyguard_screen_tab_unlock.xml

Should be some keyguard_* layout and the source for the digital clock widget would be

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/DigitalClock.java

Edit: github seems to be outdated, the following ones should be more accurate

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2_r1/core/res/res/layout/keyguard_screen_tab_unlock.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/DigitalClock.java

Comment: When used in an ACtivity, it work more or less (hour is not in bold) and the date is not in the layout, that's why I believe that's not the correct layout. When used in a widget "problem loading widget" with no extra information in logcat

Comment: You are right, but https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/res/layout/desk_clock_time_date.xml , https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/DigitalClock.java looks good (should be the clock widget with the same layout and it has style="@style/big_bold" / style="@style/big_thin" for hours / minutes https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/res/values/styles.xml)

Comment: i cant make this work :( could you help me with example? i tried and i cant i fix the code and when i tried use on the xml says onFinishInflate has Null exception java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.zenkun.mycardashboard.views.DigitalClock.onFinishInflate(DigitalClock.java:178)

Answer (score 1):

Google has provided something really usefull:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

zapi links are giving the same results, thanks for the help.